# Ampscript / CONTAINS and BEGIN WITH functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

What should be the syntax in AMPSCRIPT for:

```
%%[IF @variable CONTAINS "xxx" THEN]%% %%=ContentBlockByID("83290")=%%

and 

%%[IF @variable BEGINS WITH "xxx" THEN]%% %%=ContentBlockByID("83290")=%% 

?
```

Is there any simple syntax ? 
Would you have some examples ? I found some stuff about it on forum but it is not very clear to me.

Comment: A simple Google of "ampscript string functions" reveals all. Consider https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/IndexOf.htm as the solution to both.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these cases can be covered by the IndexOf function. See the [product documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/IndexOf.htm).

Contains can be modelled by checking that Index Of is not zero.

Starts With can be modelled by checking that Index Of is 1.

Comment: Although somewhat accurate, your answer contains no actual explanation on how IndexOf solves this. Both `Contains` and `Begins With` are normal simple operators used in filters for many other languages - making the question is valid. Without knowledge that these do not exist in AMPscript, there is no reason for the asker to consider to look at IndexOf nor does the documentation explicitly state anything about how IndexOf solves this.  As mentioned in comments, the solution is well documented elsewhere, but that is not a valid reason to be dismissive or rude.

Comment: Also as a note, your comment is a much better place for this, and I have upvoted it as it is accurate. I am saying the above as an answer is inappropriate.

Comment: @Gortonington, I have added the obvious mapping of Contains and Starts With to Index Of. I hope this is enough for you to remove your down vote (which I feel to be rather harsh).

Comment: A downvote was unwarranted, you are correct. I apologize and have removed it. I just want to try and make SFSE a more welcoming environment for those new to the system or programming in general. It is a great place to learn and the less snarky responses provided, the more people that will join and interact.

Comment: I am really sorry for the heated discussion...! but I initially don't code at all, I had to start with SFMC and the logic of ampscript is not always easy for me. Thank you for your replies. For "Begins with", would it be relevant to use "Substring(1, 2, 3)" ? Actually I want to write a condition with POST CODE that should start with "92" or "93" for example.

Comment: Hey, no worries. I was, it must be said, rather terse and blunt for which I apologise. Anyway, to your question, you could substring compare if you like, though using Index Of will be more flexible (you don't have to worry how long the string you are comparing the value with actually is, whereas you would using substring).

Comment: That's alright :) I guess that you are used to people often asking the same questions...! Finally I used Substring(1, 2, 3) to translate "begins with", it worked and it was easier. Because I had many dynamic blocks that should vary depending on groups of postcodes beginning with 2 specific digits.

Comment: And with IndexOf I feared that I had to write one condition per postcode, and there are many. Here is the beginning of my ampscript :   %%[Set DEPARTEMENT = Substring(POSTCODE,1,2)]               
%%[IF DEPARTEMENT  == "62" OR DEPARTEMENT  == "59" OR DEPARTEMENT  == "80" THEN]%%          
%%=ContentBlockByID("83299")=%% Are my fears warranted ?

Comment: This works for your use case, so stick with it.